# VB6 Application Compiled files

Tags: vb6

I'm new at VB6 and now the source code of a web application by the outsource is giving me error on every control.
So I check with the outsource and he asked me to check the compiled .exe file.

Any idea about compiled .exe file? Is it same as publishing in vb.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are the same (not sure about VB.net) but you can easily make an EXE by clicking on the Make "ProjectName".exe item in the file menu, specify the path and VIOLA! run it from there.

[Tutorial Here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/how-compile-stand-alone-executable)